Aeron untethered subscriptions struggle to reconnect
Our application listens to a stream of data and we currently have tethering disabled with default settings on the tethering window limit and resting timeouts. There's multiple subscribers to this stream spread across four servers, and a separate server publishing to the stream.
We had one one subscriber on a server fall behind the stream and start printing this
[ERROR] 2024-04-02 13:17:59.768 [aeron-client-conductor] AeronUtil - Unavailable image on aeron:udp?endpoint=239.0.0.3:43003|interface=192.168.178.0/24|fc=min - streamId=2000 sessionId=1176002113 registrationId=106 from 192.168.178.9:46452
[INFO ] 2024-04-02 13:18:14.769 [aeron-client-conductor] AeronUtil - Available image on aeron:udp?endpoint=239.0.0.3:43003|interface=192.168.178.0/24|fc=min - streamId=2000 sessionId=1176002113 registrationId=106 from 192.168.178.9:46452
[ERROR] 2024-04-02 13:18:19.776 [aeron-client-conductor] AeronUtil - Unavailable image on aeron:udp?endpoint=239.0.0.3:43003|interface=192.168.178.0/24|fc=min - streamId=2000 sessionId=1176002113 registrationId=106 from 192.168.178.9:46452
[INFO ] 2024-04-02 13:18:34.766 [aeron-client-conductor] AeronUtil - Available image on aeron:udp?endpoint=239.0.0.3:43003|interface=192.168.178.0/24|fc=min - streamId=2000 sessionId=1176002113 registrationId=106 from 192.168.178.9:46452
[ERROR] 2024-04-02 13:18:39.774 [aeron-client-conductor] AeronUtil - Unavailable image on aeron:udp?endpoint=239.0.0.3:43003|interface=192.168.178.0/24|fc=min - streamId=2000 sessionId=1176002113 registrationId=106 from 192.168.178.9:46452
[INFO ] 2024-04-02 13:18:46.096 [aeron-client-conductor] AeronUtil - Available image on aeron:udp?endpoint=239.0.0.3:43003|interface=192.168.178.0/24|fc=min - streamId=2000 sessionId=1176002113 registrationId=106 from 192.168.178.9:46452

Which continued for some 30 minutes. Using backlogstat we can see
[INFO ] 2024-04-02 13:18:07.963 [main] AeronStatWriter - sessionId=1176002113 streamId=2000 channel=aeron:udp?endpoint=239.0.0.3:43003|interface=192.168.178.0/24|fc=m : 
[INFO ] 2024-04-02 13:18:07.963 [main] AeronStatWriter - ┌─receiver 27 is at position 14978891712
[INFO ] 2024-04-02 13:18:07.963 [main] AeronStatWriter - ├─subscriber 25 has 0 backlog bytes
[INFO ] 2024-04-02 13:18:07.963 [main] AeronStatWriter - ├─subscriber 30 has 0 backlog bytes
[INFO ] 2024-04-02 13:18:07.963 [main] AeronStatWriter - ├─subscriber 58 has 0 backlog bytes
[INFO ] 2024-04-02 13:18:07.963 [main] AeronStatWriter - ├─subscriber 79 has 0 backlog bytes
[INFO ] 2024-04-02 13:18:07.963 [main] AeronStatWriter - ├─subscriber 99 has 0 backlog bytes
[INFO ] 2024-04-02 13:18:07.963 [main] AeronStatWriter - ├─subscriber 106 has 2138013088 backlog bytes
[INFO ] 2024-04-02 13:18:07.963 [main] AeronStatWriter - ├─subscriber 136 has 0 backlog bytes
[INFO ] 2024-04-02 13:18:07.963 [main] AeronStatWriter - ├─subscriber 145 has 0 backlog bytes
[INFO ] 2024-04-02 13:18:07.963 [main] AeronStatWriter - ├─subscriber 155 has 0 backlog bytes
[INFO ] 2024-04-02 13:18:07.963 [main] AeronStatWriter - ├─subscriber 165 has 0 backlog bytes
[INFO ] 2024-04-02 13:18:07.963 [main] AeronStatWriter - ├─subscriber 174 has 0 backlog bytes
[INFO ] 2024-04-02 13:18:07.963 [main] AeronStatWriter - └─subscriber 183 has 0 backlog bytes

The one subscriber seems to be about 2 gigabytes behind. We can check the sub-pos in this same time...
176:       12,840,878,624 - sub-pos: 106 1176002113 2000 aeron:udp?endpoint=239.0.0.3:43003|interface=192.168.178.0/24|fc=min @2478432
176:       12,840,878,624 - sub-pos: 106 1176002113 2000 aeron:udp?endpoint=239.0.0.3:43003|interface=192.168.178.0/24|fc=min @2478432
176:       12,840,878,624 - sub-pos: 106 1176002113 2000 aeron:udp?endpoint=239.0.0.3:43003|interface=192.168.178.0/24|fc=min @2478432
176:       12,840,878,624 - sub-pos: 106 1176002113 2000 aeron:udp?endpoint=239.0.0.3:43003|interface=192.168.178.0/24|fc=min @2478432
176:       12,840,878,624 - sub-pos: 106 1176002113 2000 aeron:udp?endpoint=239.0.0.3:43003|interface=192.168.178.0/24|fc=min @2478432
176:       12,840,878,624 - sub-pos: 106 1176002113 2000 aeron:udp?endpoint=239.0.0.3:43003|interface=192.168.178.0/24|fc=min @2478432
176:       12,840,878,624 - sub-pos: 106 1176002113 2000 aeron:udp?endpoint=239.0.0.3:43003|interface=192.168.178.0/24|fc=min @2478432
176:       12,840,878,624 - sub-pos: 106 1176002113 2000 aeron:udp?endpoint=239.0.0.3:43003|interface=192.168.178.0/24|fc=min @2478432
176:       12,840,878,624 - sub-pos: 106 1176002113 2000 aeron:udp?endpoint=239.0.0.3:43003|interface=192.168.178.0/24|fc=min @2478432

And the sub-pos is firmly stuck at the same number. These logs have a 10 second gap between them.
Our best theory for what's going on is when it reconnects it tries to consume the entire buffer in the receiver, which causes the subscriber to immediately have less than 1/8th of its window left and fall behind. Or alternatively, the subscriber's image doesn't flush before reconnecting and is immediately behind as well.
This eventually resolved when every single subscriber to this stream printed Unavailable image and the stuck stream immediately had a zero backlog. After that, it seemed fine. It's a bit odd though because the other subscribers printed Unavailable image and reconnected after ~300 milliseconds. So it doesn't seem like the other subscribers actually fell behind or anything.
This is the media driver context
MediaDriver.Context{
    isClosed=false
    cncVersion=0.2.0
    aeronDirectoryName=/dev/shm/aeronmediadriver
    driverTimeoutMs=10000
    printConfigurationOnStart=true
    useWindowsHighResTimer=true
    warnIfDirectoryExists=false
    dirDeleteOnStart=true
    dirDeleteOnShutdown=false
    termBufferSparseFile=false
    performStorageChecks=true
    spiesSimulateConnection=true
    reliableStream=true
    tetherSubscriptions=false
    rejoinStream=true
    receiverGroupConsideration=INFER
    conductorBufferLength=1049344
    toClientsBufferLength=1048704
    counterValuesBufferLength=1048576
    errorBufferLength=1048576
    lowStorageWarningThreshold=167772160
    timerIntervalNs=1000000000
    clientLivenessTimeoutNs=20000000000
    imageLivenessTimeoutNs=10000000000
    publicationUnblockTimeoutNs=40000000000
    publicationConnectionTimeoutNs=5000000000
    publicationLingerTimeoutNs=5000000000
    untetheredWindowLimitTimeoutNs=5000000000
    untetheredRestingTimeoutNs=10000000000
    retransmitUnicastDelayNs=0
    retransmitUnicastLingerNs=60000000
    nakUnicastDelayNs=60000000
    nakMulticastMaxBackoffNs=60000000
    nakMulticastGroupSize=10
    statusMessageTimeoutNs=200000000
    counterFreeToReuseTimeoutNs=1000000000
    publicationTermBufferLength=134217728
    ipcTermBufferLength=67108864
    publicationTermWindowLength=0
    ipcPublicationTermWindowLength=0
    initialWindowLength=2097152
    socketSndbufLength=2097152
    socketRcvbufLength=2097152
    socketMulticastTtl=0
    mtuLength=1408
    ipcMtuLength=1408
    filePageSize=4096
    publicationReservedSessionIdLow=-1
    publicationReservedSessionIdHigh=1000
    lossReportBufferLength=1048576
    epochClock=org.agrona.concurrent.SystemEpochClock@58670130
    nanoClock=org.agrona.concurrent.SystemNanoClock@74e47444
    cachedEpochClock=org.agrona.concurrent.CachedEpochClock@9bd0fa6
    cachedNanoClock=org.agrona.concurrent.CachedNanoClock@59d2103b
    threadingMode=DEDICATED
    conductorThreadFactory=com.nmf.client.aeron.LowLatencyMediaDriver$$Lambda$112/0x00007fb50d21bc40@39dcf4b0
    senderThreadFactory=com.nmf.client.aeron.LowLatencyMediaDriver$$Lambda$113/0x00007fb50d21acb0@6e4de19b
    receiverThreadFactory=com.nmf.client.aeron.LowLatencyMediaDriver$$Lambda$114/0x00007fb50d2198b0@f6c03cb
    sharedThreadFactory=com.nmf.client.aeron.LowLatencyMediaDriver$$Lambda$111/0x00007fb50d21c440@46f699d5
    sharedNetworkThreadFactory=com.nmf.client.aeron.LowLatencyMediaDriver$$Lambda$111/0x00007fb50d21c440@46f699d5
    conductorIdleStrategy=BusySpinIdleStrategy{alias=spin}
    senderIdleStrategy=NoOpIdleStrategy{alias=noop}
    receiverIdleStrategy=NoOpIdleStrategy{alias=noop}
    sharedNetworkIdleStrategy=BusySpinIdleStrategy{alias=spin}
    sharedIdleStrategy=BusySpinIdleStrategy{alias=spin}
    sendChannelEndpointSupplier=io.aeron.driver.DefaultSendChannelEndpointSupplier@18518ccf
    receiveChannelEndpointSupplier=io.aeron.driver.DefaultReceiveChannelEndpointSupplier@1991f767
    receiveChannelEndpointThreadLocals=io.aeron.driver.media.ReceiveChannelEndpointThreadLocals@768ccdc5
    tempBuffer=UnsafeBuffer{addressOffset=24, capacity=512, byteArray=[B@4c6daf0, byteBuffer=null}
    unicastFlowControlSupplier=DefaultUnicastFlowControlSupplier{flowControlClass=io.aeron.driver.UnicastFlowControl}
    multicastFlowControlSupplier=DefaultMulticastFlowControlSupplier{flowControlClass=io.aeron.driver.MaxMulticastFlowControl}
    applicationSpecificFeedback=[]
    receiverGroupTag=null
    flowControlGroupTag=-1
    flowControlGroupMinSize=0
    flowControlReceiverTimeoutNs=5000000000
    reResolutionCheckIntervalNs=1000000000
    receiverGroupConsideration=INFER
    congestionControlSupplier=io.aeron.driver.DefaultCongestionControlSupplier@10650953
    terminationValidator=io.aeron.driver.DefaultDenyTerminationValidator@659eef7
    terminationHook=null
    nameResolver=io.aeron.driver.DefaultNameResolver@162be91c
    resolverName=null
    resolverInterface=null
    resolverBootstrapNeighbor=null
    sendToStatusMessagePollRatio=6
    unicastFeedbackDelayGenerator=StaticDelayGenerator{delayInNs=60000000, shouldFeedbackImmediately=true}
    multicastFeedbackDelayGenerator=OptimalMulticastDelayGenerator{randMax=5.5043084883234095E-8, baseX=2.1022597447284334E-9, constantT=1.8167586393846832E7, factorT=4.7567861321968967E8, shouldFeedbackImmediately=false}
    retransmitUnicastDelayGenerator=StaticDelayGenerator{delayInNs=0, shouldFeedbackImmediately=false}
    retransmitUnicastLingerGenerator=StaticDelayGenerator{delayInNs=60000000, shouldFeedbackImmediately=false}
    errorLog=org.agrona.concurrent.errors.DistinctErrorLog@1c9f0a20
    errorHandler=org.agrona.concurrent.errors.LoggingErrorHandler@55787112
    useConcurrentCountersManager=false
    countersManager=org.agrona.concurrent.status.CountersManager@1cd201a8
    systemCounters=io.aeron.driver.status.SystemCounters@7db82169
    lossReport=io.aeron.driver.reports.LossReport@1992eaf4
    logFactory=io.aeron.driver.buffer.FileStoreLogFactory@f74e835
    dataTransportPoller=io.aeron.driver.media.DataTransportPoller@3276732
    controlTransportPoller=io.aeron.driver.media.ControlTransportPoller@3f28bd56
    driverCommandQueue=org.agrona.concurrent.ManyToOneConcurrentArrayQueue@31e3250d
    receiverCommandQueue=org.agrona.concurrent.OneToOneConcurrentArrayQueue@19fe4644
    senderCommandQueue=org.agrona.concurrent.OneToOneConcurrentArrayQueue@21d8bcbe
    receiverProxy=io.aeron.driver.ReceiverProxy@5be067de
    senderProxy=io.aeron.driver.SenderProxy@7383eae2
    driverConductorProxy=io.aeron.driver.DriverConductorProxy@18245eb0
    clientProxy=io.aeron.driver.ClientProxy@7c7d3c46
    toDriverCommands=org.agrona.concurrent.ringbuffer.ManyToOneRingBuffer@24fb6a80
    lossReportBuffer=java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=1048576 cap=1048576]
    cncByteBuffer=java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=8392704 cap=8392704]
    cncMetaDataBuffer=UnsafeBuffer{addressOffset=140415570628608, capacity=48, byteArray=null, byteBuffer=java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=8392704 cap=8392704]}
}

aeron-driver is 1.32.0 in our pom.xml. We're using the Java media driver
We're expecting the lagging subscription to only log Unavailable image once, then reconnect straight after that. However, it went back and forth for 30+ minutes.
On the github wiki we can see this

If the subscriber does not wish to rest then they can close the subscription and add a new one.

For this behaviour of flushing the entire cache, is closing and reconnecting on unavailable image a better approach than relying on the untethered subscriptions behaviour? What is untethered actually doing in that period where it's flicking between unavailable and available image?
